# Личные сообщения на сайте

Tags: mysql

Всем доброе утро и удачного дня!
Озадачился тут созданием на сайте сервиса личных сообщений между пользователями.
Для mysql примерно набросал 2 варианта таблиц.

*Вариант 1, с двумя таблицами.*

**pm_dialog**

```
id (id диалога)
user_from (от)
user_to (кому)
unread (флаг прочитано ли нет)
status_from (статус у отправителя, напр.удаленное)
status_to (статус у получателя)
```

**pm_mess**

```
id (id сообщения)
dialog (id диалога)
user (от)
date (дата)
text (сообщение)
```

*Вариант 2, с одной таблицей*

**messages**

```
id (id сообщения)
user_from (от)
user_to (кому)
text (сообщение)
date (дата)
unread (флаг прочитано ли нет)
status_from (статус у отправителя, напр.удаленное)
status_to (статус у получателя)
```

Помогите пожалуйста составить mysql запросы в любом из вариантов чтобы была возможность вывести список диалогов по дате, и вместо темы начало текста последнего сообщения, а также запрос на вывод всех сообщений определенного диалога. Вчера просидел весь день, гуглил, но в основном везде отдельными сообщениями без объединения в диалоги

Comment: INSERT INTO table(колонки) VALUES(данные)
я не пойму что тут составлять. делайте обычные записи.

Comment: я за выборку а не за вставку записи спрашивал

Answer (score 1):

Давно с SQL базами не работал.
Под последний запрос выборка будет как то так:

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `user_from` = 'от кого' AND `user_to` = 'кому' ORDER BY data DESC
```